# Specific password generator pattern -- how to reproduce?

Tags: linux, passwords, generator

Some time ago I created a couple of passwords that turned out very useful for everyday use, the pattern is like this:

```
LLL-NNN-LLL-NNN-LLL-NNN-LLL
```

whereas

```
LLL = lower or upper case letter
```

with `NNN = number`.

Unfortunately, I forgot which tool I used to create these passwords. I was hoping that there is a Linux command line tool to create this kind of pattern.

Comment: You want pure pseudo-random selection of all the groups, or do you want to seed it using one or more characteristics of the website's URL (which makes it MUCH easier to remember but decreases entropy)? Either way, you can do it in Libre Calc, and let it also store the passwords for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I knew how to do that from the comand line, but here's a purely pseudorandom method using Libre Calc, or Open Office Calc.

Create an seven column sheet.  The  seven columns are generated pseudorandomly by two formulae at every recalculation; to force Calc to recalculate manually, press Shift+Ctrl+F9.

The numerical columns should be formatted to show three integers including leading zeros and use the formula

```
INT(RAND()*(1000))
```

The text columns use the formula:

```
MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",(RANDBETWEEN(1,52)),1)&MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",(RANDBETWEEN(1,52)),1)&MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",(RANDBETWEEN(1,52)),1)
```